# Converting a matrix into a tibble in R

Tags: r, matrix, tibble

How can I convert this matrix:

```
> matrix(1:3, nrow = 3, dimnames = list(c("X","Y","Z"), c("A")))
  A
X 1
Y 2
Z 3
```

into this tibble:

```
> tibble::tribble(~group1, ~group2, ~value, "X", "A", 1, "Y", "A", 2, "Z", "A", 3)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  group1 group2 value
  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>
1 X      A          1
2 Y      A          2
3 Z      A          3
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as.tibble` can convert the matrix's `rownames` to a column, and then you can use `gather()` to create the `group2` column:

```
library(tidyverse)

m <- matrix(1:3, nrow = 3, dimnames = list(c("X","Y","Z"), c("A")))

newtib <- m %>%
    as.tibble(rownames = "group1") %>%
    gather('A', key = "group2", value = "value")

> newtib
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  group1 group2 value
  <chr>  <chr>  <int>
1 X      A          1
2 Y      A          2
3 Z      A          3

> tibble::tribble(~group1, ~group2, ~value, "X", "A", 1, "Y", "A", 2, "Z", "A", 3)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  group1 group2 value
  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>
1 X      A          1
2 Y      A          2
3 Z      A          3
```

Answer (score 4):

Easier with `base R`, if we convert to `table` and coerce with `as.data.frame` (if we need to convert to `tibble` - use `as_tibble` as wrapper over the `as.data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(as.table(m1))
  Var1 Var2 Freq
1    X    A    1
2    Y    A    2
3    Z    A    3
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(1:3, nrow = 3, dimnames = list(c("X","Y","Z"), c("A")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use -

```
library(tidyverse)

mat <- matrix(1:3, nrow = 3, dimnames = list(c("X","Y","Z"), c("A")))

mat  %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = 'group1') %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -group1, names_to = 'group2')

#  group1 group2 value
#  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>
#1 X      A          1
#2 Y      A          2
#3 Z      A          3
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Transform your matrix into a dataframe
2. bring your rownames to column `group1`
3. mutate `group2`

```
data.frame(matrix) %>% 
  rownames_to_column("group1") %>% 
  mutate(group2 = colnames(matrix)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(group1, group2, value=A)
```

```
  group1 group2 value
1      X      A     1
2      Y      A     2
3      Z      A     3
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with

```
m <- matrix(1:3, nrow = 3, dimnames = list(c("X","Y","Z"), c("A")))
tibble(
    group1 = rownames(m)[row(m)]
    ,group2 = colnames(m)[col(m)]
    ,value = c(m)
)
```

Which:

- generalizes to the case with multiple columns
- will be fast for the large matrices
- it's very simple

Answer (score 0):

You have two more base R options

```
> as.data.frame.table(mat)
  Var1 Var2 Freq
1    X    A    1
2    Y    A    2
3    Z    A    3
```

or

```
> cbind(expand.grid(dimnames(mat)), mat)
  Var1 Var2 A
X    X    A 1
Y    Y    A 2
Z    Z    A 3
```

## Data

```
mat <- matrix(1:3, nrow = 3, dimnames = list(c("X", "Y", "Z"), c("A")))
```